# Basic Python Calculation

Tags: python-3.x

How would you get 1.75 if:

```
num2=24
num1=3
total=14

print('Subtotal left: %.1f' % (num2/(num1*total)))
```

Is their another way to write this calculation to get that result? I can only get 0.4, 2.3 etc etc I know Python follows PEMDAS I've tried all night to get that result but unfortunately I'm not smart enough with Python yet.

Please Help! :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
14/(24/3)==1.75
```

I'll leave the coding to you.

Comment: Cheers, I see the calculation does yield that number but arranging the math in the Python code only yields 2.3?

Comment: @user1291271, show us your code. in the python interpreter `>>14/(24/3.0) >>1.75`

Comment: Then you need more help with Python than I can provide.

Comment: lol that's most of it so far, it's an exercise I'm doing. If I do (3*14)/24 it yields 1.75 which is the result I'm after.

Comment: @user291271: It's usually better to make the calculation match what you are calculating, not just arrange it so that it gets the number you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
result = (total*num1)/num2
print("Subtotal left: %f" % result)
```

Output:

```
Subtotal left: 1.75
```